# Doctrine ODM @Distance in yaml

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-odm

How I can add @Distance in yaml mapping file ? I tried it and not works.

```
CP\AppBundle\Document\Point:
  type: embeddedDocument
  embedOne:
    address:
      targetDocument: CP\AppBundle\Document\Address
    coordinates:
      targetDocument: CP\AppBundle\Document\Coordinates
  distance: distance
  indexes:
    coordinates:
      keys:
        coordinates: 2d
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

The distance field needs to be specified as a float with a distance parameter:

```
CP\AppBundle\Document\Point:
  type: embeddedDocument
  embedOne:
    address:
      targetDocument: CP\AppBundle\Document\Address
    coordinates:
      targetDocument: CP\AppBundle\Document\Coordinates
  fields:
    distance:
      type: float
      distance: true
  indexes:
    coordinates:
      keys:
        coordinates: 2d
```